# Git Commit-Msg in Python. Getting an EOF Error

Tags: python, git, input, commit, eof

I am creating a commit-msg for .git/hooks/commit-msg and I am getting an EOF Error when asking user for input() on this line
`response = input("Are you sure you want to commit? [y/N]: ")`
if anyone could help me figure out what is wrong!

[Output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypbPW.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re


def main():
    # open file to read every lines
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()

        for idx, line in enumerate(lines):

            if line.strip() == "# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------":
                break

            if line[0] == "#":
                continue

    # warning message
    if (re.search('#[0-9]+$', line) is None):
        print("Warning: add issue number related to this commit.")
        # ask user to confirm until valid response
        try:
            while True:
                response = input("Are you sure you want to commit? [y/N]: ")
                if (response == 'y'):
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif (response == 'N'):
                    sys.exit(1)
        except EOFError as e:
            print(e)
    
    # successful commit
    print("Success: Perfect commit!")
    sys.exit(0)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `commit-msg` hook is run with no standard input (more specifically, standard input is redirected from `/dev/null`), and therefore any attempt to read from standard input will immediately read EOF.

You could try reading from `/dev/tty` if standard output is a TTY, but be aware that it isn't guaranteed that you'll have one at all.  Commits can be run noninteractively without any terminal at all, and the hooks are not designed to be interactive.  You'll have to decide what you want to do in that case.